# How to avoid "CALL SCREEN(not modal) in modal dialog box not allowed"?

Tags: abap, dynpro

I am creating a SAP Program in which there's more that 200 parameters

```
PARAMETERS: P_DATE type D default Sy-DATUM.
PARAMETERS: P_DATE2 type D default Sy-DATUM
.
.
.
PARAMETERS: P_DATE2 type D default Sy-DATUM
```

When I compile it, I got the following errormessage:

```
CALL SCREEN(not modal) in modal dialog box not allowed
```

It works if I have only about 190 parameters. It could be just some limits. Any ideas? Thank you in

Comment: It seems some parameter causes this error, not the limitation on number of parameters. Try to sequentially add each of these 10 parameters and see which one throws it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It still failed when it reaches 200 parameters. Do you know if there's a limit somewhere ?

Comment: No, there is no known limit in documentation. Either one of your parameters is corrupted or invalid, either you are revealed new bug in SAP:)

Comment: Give us full code of your selection screen.

Answer (score 3):

Screens (dynpros) can only have 200 lines ([as mentioned in the screen painter documentation](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_sm71_sp10/helpdata/en/d1/801b84454211d189710000e8322d00/frameset.htm)). Without further positioning instructions, each `PARAMETERS` declaration creates a new line on the selection screen.

(Other than that, requiring 200 parameters strongly suggests a design flaw somewhere in your application. I doubt that any user will be able to make sense of the selection screen.)

Comment: Thanks to all! @vwegert , is there a way to increase the maximum rows to more than 200 ?

Comment: @Suncatcher Hi, what I have posted is my code but with more than 200 lines. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the positioning features of the selection screen you can place more than one parameter in one line. Check the command `SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF LINE` and `SELECTION-SCREEN POSITION`, more about these [here](http://help-legacy.sap.com/abapdocu_751/en/abapselection-screen_line.htm).